# where to define user defined message to display in package manager console?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is this possible to show a user defined message in package manager console while running a Seed method or throwing any exceptions?

When i am getting below error message from package manager console when throwing exception while running Seed method from Packager manager console my running Seed method has been stopped and not able to process for other seed methods! so I used Try-Catch block to skip those exception and continue other seed methods.

***Object reference not set to an instance of an object.***

My Seed Methods Seems like this:

```
context.Subjects.AddOrUpdate(MyRepository.SeedSubject.Subject());
```

> BookTypes

```
context.BookTypes.AddOrUpdate(b => b.Type,
new BookType { Type = "Audio" },
new BookType { Type = "Book" },               
new BookType { Type = "Video" }       
);
```

> Books

```
context.Books.AddOrUpdate(FCA.Repository.SeedBook.Books());
try
   {
    context.BookSubjects.AddOrUpdate(b => b.BookSubjectID,
    new BookSubject { SubjectID = context.Subjects.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Graduation").SubjectID, BookID = context.Books.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Title == "Graduation Event").BookID },
    new BookSubject { SubjectID = context.Subjects.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Online Courses").SubjectID, BookID = context.Books.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Title == "3rd Grade Online Complete Set").BookID },                                      
    new BookSubject { SubjectID = context.Subjects.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Name == "8th Grade").SubjectID, BookID = context.Books.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Title == "Access 2000 Set Lifepac").BookID });
   }
catch (Exception ex)
   {                
     //How to display this message in Package Manager Console  while running Seed method?
   }
```

How can i show user defined messages in package manager console Or Is this possible to run Seed method with Break-Point?